# Can you place a DataItem into a LayoutTemplate as im trying and its not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to wrap the Items in a wrapper to which i need to also pass a few bits of data:

```
<asp:ListView ID="rptListingAllMandatoryCourses" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptListingAllMandatoryCourses_ItemDataBound">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <Catalogue title="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CatalogueTitle")%>" description="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CatalogueDescription")%>">
      <div runat="server" ID="groupPlaceholder"></div>
    </Catalogue>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <GroupTemplate> 
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
  </GroupTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <Course>
      <CourseTitle><a onclick="linkcourse("<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseID")%>");return false;" href="#" title="Launch <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseTitle")%>"><%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode((String)(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseTitle").ToString().Length > 25 ? DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseTitle").ToString().Remove(22) + "..." : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseTitle")))%></a></CourseTitle>
      <RatingsEnabled><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ratingsEnabled")%></RatingsEnabled>
      <Rating><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "rating")%></Rating>
      <RatingCommentsEnabled><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ratingCommentsEnabled")%></RatingCommentsEnabled>
      <Comment><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comment")%></Comment>
    </Course>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

But i get this error:

> CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItem' does not contain a definition for 'DataItem' and no extension method 'DataItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Breaks at this point

```
<Catalogue title="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CatalogueTitle")%>" description="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CatalogueDescription")%>"> <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" /> </Catalogue>
```

If i remove the DataItems of course it works, and those DataItem's work when inside the ItemTemplate but really do need to pass those 2 bits of data to wrapper

Anyone have any ideas? sorry i'm not a asp.net guy so trying to crack it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry about that, noted for the future.

Comment: It looks like you should use a `GridView` instead of `ListView`. `DataItem` belongs to `GridViewRow`. The `ListViewItem` doesn't keep reference to an object.

Comment: Ok, i would  have no idea how to do that, never done asp and been given this task to fix at work. Will it work how i need it to though if i do this?

Comment: You can definitely use this kind of binding with the `GridView`

Comment: Ive been reading up on it but struggling, you have no idea how long it took me to do the above lol

Comment: Could you maybe or someone do me an example based on mine above please? i only have a few hours to get this done :(